# Undefined variable: dataP (View: D:\wamp\www\BTPl\resources\views\salarie\payer.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner at laravel,I have two form form1 which contains year and month and radio buttons of 1st and 2nd quanziane and selects of Salaries and chantiers and button when I click on button cherche for form1 to hide and form2 to display and also I get data according to the conditions of the form1 fields I use ajax this data I want to display it in form 2 table,for explain more I have `Salaries` working on `Chantiers` and who must point the day work every day, table `Pointages` contain id, `Chantier_id` foreign key of table `Chantiers` where they work, `ouvrage_id` (foreign key of table `ouvrages`) task gives to perform, `datep` date of Pointages, `Sold` price of Salaries for day, now I want to display in the table of balde `payer.balde.php` The total salaire of the worker who owes it to the company in which he works is per month or the 1st somaine of the month or the 2nd somaine of the month, depending on the client's choice, I could have data in the console but when I want to display it in my blade I get this error someone can resolve this error.

**payer.balde.php**

```
              <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                 <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
                    <th>Anne</th>
                    <th>mois</th>
                    <th>matricule </th>
                    <th>prenom</th>
                    <th>salaire Net</th>
                    <th>sold</th>
                    <th>edit</th>
                    <th>delete</th>
                    <th>details</th>
                  </tr>
                 </thead>
                <tbody>
                  @foreach($dataP as $salarie)
                  <tr id="{{$salarie->id}}">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="customer_id[]" value="{{$salarie->id}}" /></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" class='year' class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><input type="hidden" class='month' class="form-control" /></td>
                    <td>{{ $salarie->id }} </td>
                    <td>{{ $salarie->nom }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $salarie->prenom }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $salarie->sold }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ url('salaries/'.$salarie->id.'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-theme03 btn-sm">Editer</a></td>
                <form action="{{ url('salaries', ['id' => $salarie->id]) }}" method="post">
                  {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme04 btn-sm" role="button">Delete</button></td>
                </form>
                    <td><a href="{{ url('salaries/'.$salarie->id) }}" class="btn btn-theme02 btn-sm" role="button">Show</a></td>
                  </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
            <tfoot>
             <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>annee</th>
                    <th>mois</th>
                    <th>matricule </th>
                    <th>nom</th>
                    <th>prevom</th>
                    <th>sold</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
             </tr>
        </tfoot>
   </table>

         </div>
</div>
        <!------------->
      </section>
    </section>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
         if($(this).is(':checked',true)){
          $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);
          } else {  
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked',false);}  
          });
         $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
            if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',true);
            }else{
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',false);}
         });

         $("#form2").hide();
          let now = new Date();
          let year = now.getFullYear();
          let month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
          $('#annee').val(year);
          $('#mois').val(month); 


        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("#form1").hide();
            $("#form2").show();
            let chan = $("#chantier_id option:selected").text();
            $('#ch').text(chan);
            let sal = $("#salarie_id option:selected").text();
            $('#sa').text(sal);
            let ann = $("#annee").val();
            $('#an').text(ann);
            let moi = $("#mois").val();
            $('#mo').text(moi);
            $('.year').text(ann);
            let chan_id = $("#chantier_id option:selected").val();
            let sal_id = $("#salarie_id option:selected").val();
            $('.month').val(mois).parent().prepend(moi);
            $('.year').val(ann).parent().prepend(ann);
          var radioValue = $("input[name='quanzaime']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue){
                console.log(radioValue); 
            }
             $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: "{{ route('salarie.payerP') }}",
          data: {
                 'quanzaime':radioValue,
                 'annee':ann,
                 'mois':moi,
                 'salarie_id':sal_id,
                 'chantier_id':chan_id 
                },
          success: function(data1){
            console.log(data1);   
          },
          error: function(){
              console.log('error');
          },
          });
            });
  });
  </script>
```

**SalarieController.php**

```
  public function payer(){
      $pointages = Pointage::get();
      $salaries = Salarie::get();
      $chantiers = Chantier::get();
      return view('salarie.payer', compact('salaries','pointages','chantiers'));
    }

     public function payerP(request $request){
      if($request->quanzaime == 1){
        $dataP = DB::table('salaries')
         ->join('pointages','pointages.salarie_id','salaries.id')
          ->selectRaw('SUM(pointages.sold) as sold,salaries.nom,salaries.prenom,salaries.id')
          ->whereRaw(DB::raw('YEAR(pointages.datep) = ' .$request->annee))
          ->whereRaw(DB::raw('MONTH(pointages.datep) = ' .$request->mois))
          ->whereRaw( DB::raw('DAY(pointages.datep)>0 AND DAY(pointages.datep)<16')) 
          ->Orwhere('pointages.salarie_id','=',$request->salarie_id)->OrWhere('pointages.chantier_id','=',$request->chantier_id)
          ->groupBy('pointages.salarie_id')
          ->get();
          return response()->json(['salarie'=>$dataP]);
        }elseif($request->quanzaime == 2){
          $dataP = DB::table('salaries')
         ->join('pointages','pointages.salarie_id','salaries.id')
          ->selectRaw('SUM(pointages.sold) as sold,salaries.nom,salaries.prenom,salaries.id')
          ->whereRaw(DB::raw('YEAR(pointages.datep) = ' .$request->annee))
          ->whereRaw(DB::raw('MONTH(pointages.datep) = ' .$request->mois))
          ->whereRaw( DB::raw('DAY(pointages.datep)>15 AND DAY(pointages.datep)<31')) 
          ->Orwhere('pointages.salarie_id','=',$request->salarie_id)->OrWhere('pointages.chantier_id','=',$request->chantier_id)
          ->groupBy('pointages.salarie_id')
          ->get();
          return response()->json(['salarie'=>$dataP]);

        }else{ 
          $dataP = DB::table('salaries')
         ->join('pointages','pointages.salarie_id','salaries.id')
          ->selectRaw('SUM(pointages.sold) as sold,salaries.nom,salaries.prenom,salaries.id')
          ->whereRaw(DB::raw('YEAR(pointages.datep) = ' .$request->annee))
          ->whereRaw(DB::raw('MONTH(pointages.datep) = ' .$request->mois))
          ->Orwhere('pointages.salarie_id','=',$request->salarie_id)->OrWhere('pointages.chantier_id','=',$request->chantier_id)
          ->groupBy('pointages.salarie_id')
          ->get();
          return response()->json(['salarie'=>$dataP]);

        }
        //dd($request);

    }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/payer','SalarieController@payer'); 
Route::get('/payerP','SalarieController@payerP')->name('salarie.payerP');
```

Comment: Welcome. You need to pass the data to the view, you don't seem to do that, that's why `$dataP` is not available: https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: @kerbholz yes exactly and what there is method to pass data to view in this case

Comment: What, don't quite understand that comment. In `return view('salarie.payer', compact('salaries','pointages','chantiers'));` you're passing `salaries`, which will be available as `$salaries` in your view etc. Add `dataP` where neccessary

Comment: @kerbholz i edit my publish if u can understand